# jQuery disable input field when specific input field is focused

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I got two input fields and I want the other one to be disabled if the other one has a value in it. I tried it using jQuery but nothing is happening. Can someone know what should I do about this? Thanks

My input field

```
<ul>
<li id="fixedSalaryList"><b>Fixed Salary (Monthly)</b>
    <a href="#" class="show-input">$<?php echo $data['app1']['salary']; ?> <img src="<?php echo $dirimg; ?>/arrow-right.svg"></a>
    <input type="text" name="salary[]" id="fixedSalary" class="assest-input inputNumber" value="<?php echo $data['app1']['salary']; ?>" inputmode="numeric">
</li>
<li id="selfEmployedList"><b>Self-Employed Income (Annually)</b>
    <a href="#" class="show-input">$<?php echo $data['app1']['selfEmployedIncome']; ?><img src="<?php echo $dirimg; ?>/arrow-right.svg"></a>
    <input type="text" name="selfEmployedIncome[]" id="selfEmployed" class="assest-input inputNumber" value="<?php echo $data['app1']['selfEmployedIncome']; ?>" inputmode="numeric">
</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
 $('input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('input').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)
  });
```

```js
$('li input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('input').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li id="fixedSalaryList"><b>Fixed Salary (Monthly)</b>
    <a href="#" class="show-input">$</a>
    <input type="text" name="salary[]" id="fixedSalary" class="assest-input inputNumber"  inputmode="numeric">
</li>
<li id="selfEmployedList"><b>Self-Employed Income (Annually)</b>
    <a href="#" class="show-input">$</a>
    <input type="text" name="selfEmployedIncome[]" id="selfEmployed" class="assest-input inputNumber"  inputmode="numeric">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what should happen when you add text to the second text box? first one should disable?

Comment: yes. the other one will be disabled if you put text in the other textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fixedSalary").on("input", function() {
    if ($("#fixedSalary").val() != "") {
      $("#selfEmployed").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#selfEmployed").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

  $("#selfEmployed").on("input", function() {
    if ($("#selfEmployed").val() != "") {
      $("#fixedSalary").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#fixedSalary").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});

$("#btnReset").click(function() {
  $("#fixedSalary").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#selfEmployed").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="fixedSalaryList"><b>Fixed Salary (Monthly)</b>
    <a href="#" class="show-input">$</a>
    <input type="text" name="salary[]" id="fixedSalary" class="assest-input inputNumber" inputmode="numeric">
  </li>
  <li id="selfEmployedList"><b>Self-Employed Income (Annually)</b>
    <a href="#" class="show-input">$</a>
    <input type="text" name="selfEmployedIncome[]" id="selfEmployed" class="assest-input inputNumber" inputmode="numeric">
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" text="Reset" id="btnReset">
```

Comment: hmm. I want the other textbox to be disabled if you put text either of them. basically i only want one textbox. the user does not allowed to enter values in both textbox

Comment: why i cannot put input in the other textbox when i clear the other one

Comment: There are 4 textbox, so I am not understanding which one you're talking about and your fiddle works as expected, what is it you need?

Comment: I want the other textbox to be disabled if i put text on the other one and vise versa. If i clear the textbox both of them will be enabled again.

Comment: oh, so when you fill `fixed salary` you want `selfemployed` to be disabled and viceversa, my code is doing other way around is that you saying?

Comment: yes. that is exactly what i want. Thats why i send you the other fiddle

Comment: okay. this is what ive been looking for. But why your method is different from the fiddle i send to you?

Comment: in the code you sent it is checking for generic `input` type not for specific item, in my code I am checking for specific text box.

Comment: okay i see. so i need to point specific element to achieve it?

Comment: yeah your requirement needs a specific element to be checked, it is good in that way, what if there are more textbox comes in future, so that it will be helpful to handle those scenarios as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `change()` event like

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selfEmployed").change(function(){
   $("#fixedSalary").prop('disabled', true);
  });

  $("#fixedSalary").change(function(){
   $("#selfEmployed").prop('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

Now it will work both ways.

Comment: For that i have made an edit it my answer please check it.

Comment: Check out my new answer.

Comment: unfortunately its not working for me. It will not enable when i clear the value from the other textbox. but thanks. i got a new answer from the other

Comment: @KunalRaut this won't work for all scenarios, it always makes the textbox `true`.

Comment: @KunalRaut what I am trying to say is, you are using `change()` event and you should also check whether the input type is empty or not! it is not doing it, for every on change event it keep making the element `disabled` true. hope you getting what I mean.

Comment: Yes i got it now and just give me a sec i'm posting a new one .

Comment: NP, we all learn everyday, my intention was just to let you know, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is excatly waht you were looking for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selfEmployed").keyup(function(){
  if(!$("#selfEmployed").val()){
  $("#fixedSalary").prop('disabled', false);
  } 
  else {
   $("#fixedSalary").prop('disabled', true);
   }
});


  $("#fixedSalary").keyup(function(){
  if(!$("#fixedSalary").val()) {
  $("#selfEmployed").prop('disabled', false);
  } 
  else {
   $("#selfEmployed").prop('disabled', true);
   }
  }); 
});
```

Note : Remember we are doing this on the `keyup()` event so even if you erase the input it will work.